# How to conditionally change a variable in a function, based on IF-ELSE result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have navigation bar and after scroll it change color from dark to white.
On this navigation bar I have some text and I already made changing text color while scroll.
But the problem is that I have an onmouseover JS event and it changing color on hover, then on onmouseout it came back to earlier color.
When nav-bar is on dark div, nav-bar then has no background and white letters, on onmouseover it is changing to gold and then back to white.
Then when I scroll down to white div, navbar is white too, letters are black, on onmouseover its changing to gold again (thats good), but it came back to white - and they should be black again, that's the whole problem.

I have tried to put this homemouseover and homemouseout functions in if and else but they double there so I think thats why they didnt work.
I have tried to make all that color stuff in css hover too but its not working.

```
<div id="nav-bar">
  <div id="nav-bar-top">
    <div id="nav-bar-home" onmouseover="homemouseover()" onmouseout="homemouseout()" onClick="home(); homedel()">
      START
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};


//function to read a scroll level, and then set background and text color for my navigation bar

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 30 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 30) {

    document.getElementById("nav-bar").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
    document.getElementById("nav-bar-home").style.color = "#000000";

  } else {

    document.getElementById("nav-bar").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)";
    document.getElementById("nav-bar-home").style.color = "#FFFFFF";

  }
}

//two functions which works as a hovers

function homemouseover() {
    document.getElementById("nav-bar-home").style.color = "#E3B200";
}

function homemouseout() {
    document.getElementById("nav-bar-home").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

I expect to have hover like:

- dark div = no background on nav-bar, text color white, and hover like white-gold-white
- white div = white background on nav-bar, text color black, and hover like black-gold-black

It can be done in css, but I prefer to have solution in JS, thank you.

Comment: It would be simpler if you used CSS classes. Then you just have to add and remove the appropriate classes to apply different styles.

Comment: add your html code